Cauchy sequences are convergent, part of the proof verification
I just want to confirm that one particular reasoning in the proof of the theorem is correct
Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence, and let $k,N \in \mathbb N, m=N$ and $k \geq N$. Then since $x_n$ is Cauchy we have $$|x_k - x_N|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3} \implies x_N - \frac{\varepsilon}{3} < x_k < x_N + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} \quad (1)$$
which guarantees us that the Cauchy sequence is bounded, with the following argument from Zorich's Mathematical Analysis

but since only a finite number of terms of the sequence have indices not larger
than $N$, we have shown that a Cauchy/fundamental sequence is bounded.

Now, for $n \in \mathbb N$ define $a_n = \inf\limits_{k\geq n}x_k$ and $b_n = \sup\limits_{k\geq n}x_k$.
Also note that $$a_n \leq b_n \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N \quad (2)$$
The following reasoning and the bolded statements are what I want to verify:
Then from $(1), (2)$ and because $a_n$ and $b_n$ are subsequences of $x_n$ we have $$x_N - \frac{\varepsilon}{3} < a_n \leq b_n < x_N + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} \quad \forall n > N$$
and in particular because $a_n$ and $b_n$ for $n > N$ are subsequences of the subsequence $x_k$ for $k >N$.

The $\inf$ (also $\sup$) of a set if exists is a fixed number not a sequence. Also when representing a sequence we usually use the notation $(x_n)$.

@TranKhanh hm I don't see where I said that $\sup$ or $\inf$ are a sequence? not sure what you are trying to say but my guess is that it's not clear what $a_n$ is -it's the $\inf$ of all terms of $x_n$ from index $k$ onwards. e.g. if you have $x_n=(-1)^{n+1}/n$ then $a_n={-1/2, -1/2, -1/4, -1/4, \dots}$, so $a_1 = -1/2, a_2=-1/2, a_3= -1/4, ...$

Ohm, I see what you mean now. But then $(a_n)$ may not a subsequence of $(x_n)$, similar to $(b_n)$.

Your inequality is correct, but the bolded reasoning is not. As noted by Tran Khanh, is in general not true that $(a_n),(b_n)$ are both subsequences of $(x_n)$ (but see a note at the bottom). Consider the sequence given by $x_n=2^{-n}$. Then for all $n$ we have
$$a_n=\inf\{x_m:m\geq n\}=0$$
and thus $(a_n)$ is the constant zero sequence. But no $x_n$ is equal to zero, so this is not a subsequence.
However, the key point to notice is that equation (1) shows that $x_N-\varepsilon/3$ is a lower bound for the subsequence $(x_n)_{n\geq N}$. Since $a_N$ is the greatest lower bound for this subsequence, we have
$$x_N-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\leq a_N\leq a_n,\quad n\geq N$$
Analogous logic for $(b_n)$ recovers your inequality,
$$x_N-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\leq a_N\leq a_n\leq b_n\leq b_N\leq x_N+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$
From here, we can apply the monotone convergence theorem to conclude that both $\lim a_n,\lim b_n$ exist and that
$$|\lim a_n-\lim b_n|\leq \frac{2\varepsilon}{3}$$

Interestingly, if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy then it is actually the case that at least one of $(a_n),(b_n)$ is a "subsequence" of $(x_n)$, in a kind of weaker sense. Pick some $n$. If there exists $m>n$ with $b_m<b_n$, then it follows that $\sup \{x_n,\ldots,x_{m-1}\}=b_n$. Since this is a finite set, it must achieve its supremum, so there exists $x_j=b_n$. If $(b_n)$ is not eventually constant, then we can apply this logic to every $n$ to conclude that each $b_n$ is equal to some $x_m$. If $(b_n)$ is eventually constant, then this logic doesn't work, but we can attempt to do the same with $(a_n)$. This only fails if both are eventually constant, but then they must be equal at that point since $\lim a_n=\lim b_n=\lim x_n$, and then they would be equal to $x_n$ as well.
This isn't strictly a subsequence, since we may repeat elements. Consider $(x_n)=(-2)^{-n}$, where $a_n=-1/2, -1/8, -1/8, -1/32,-1/32,\ldots$ and $b_n=1/4,1/4,1/16,1/16,\ldots$. While neither is a subsequence since terms appear twice in $(a_n),(b_n)$ but only once in $(x_n)$, it is nevertheless true that each term of $(a_n)$ does appear in $(x_n)$, and that relative order is preserved when doing so, and the same for $(b_n)$.

There are also two "classic" examples: $\frac{1}{n}$ and $-\frac{1}{n}$ which, I think, are easier to remember.

Fair enough, those are probably better examples.

the notion of a subsequence i was working with while thinking actually allowed repeating terms, but ofc that’s not what a subsequence is. thanks for pointing this out and providing additional context
